# MySQL reset query cache as non-root user

Tags: mysql

As I understand it, in MySQL you can reset/clear the query cache with the following command as the root user...

```
reset query cache;
```

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to grant this privilege to another user so that they can invalidate the cache without having root access.

Comment: can you try FLUSH QUERY CACHE

Comment: why would you want to do this....??? :o

Comment: @NoobEditor, This is a testing environment but I still don't particularly want to be giving Developers root access.  In reality the query is not likely to be run very often so needs to be optimised for the likely hood that there will be no useful cache.